# Sql query for the last person in a line

Tags: sql

Table of persons who a staying in a line to an elevator:

`Queue:`

```
+-----------+-------------+--------+------+
| person_id | person_name | weight | num  |
+-----------+-------------+--------+------+
| 5         | Alice       | 250    | 1    |
| 4         | Bob         | 175    | 5    |
| 3         | Alex        | 350    | 2    |
| 6         | John Cena   | 400    | 3    |
| 1         | Winston     | 500    | 6    |
| 2         | Marie       | 200    | 4    |
+-----------+-------------+--------+------+
```

`num` is the number in the line. The elevator is able to lift up to 1000 lbs. Who is the last person coming to the elevator?

Need an sql query. (if possible without window functions)

```
result: 
+-------------+
| person_name |
+-------------+
| John Cena   |
+-------------+
```

Comment: What's the database?

Comment: "...if possible without window functions..." -- that's kind of an artificial requirement. A simple window function will produce the result you want.

Comment: ok, use window function pls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> without window functions

That makes this awkward, but still possible. I'll build the result in steps, explaining as I go.

Begin by joining the table to itself, where the join condition is everyone at the current position in line or earlier:

```
SELECT *
FROM Queue q1
JOIN Queue q2 on q2.Num <= q1.Num
```

Even with just six rows of sample data, this is already 21 rows materialized needed for this calculation, so you can see why window functions would be preferred.

Now we can `GROUP` this by the needed `q1` fields, and `SUM` the weights of `q2`:

```
SELECT q1.Num, q1.person_id, q1.person_name, SUM(q2.Weight) as TotalWeight
FROM Queue q1
JOIN Queue q2 on q2.Num <= q1.Num
GROUP BY q1.Num, q1.person_id, q1.person_name
```

Next we use a `HAVING` clause to limit the total weight.

```
SELECT q1.Num, q1.person_id, q1.person_name, SUM(q2.Weight) as TotalWeight
FROM Queue q1
JOIN Queue q2 on q2.Num <= q1.Num
GROUP BY q1.Num, q1.person_id, q1.person_name
HAVING SUM(q2.Weight) <= 1000
```

Finally, we can order things so our target record is first, and only take that first row:

```
SELECT TOP 1 q1.Num, q1.person_id, q1.person_name, SUM(q2.Weight) as TotalWeight
FROM Queue q1
JOIN Queue q2 on q2.Num <= q1.Num
GROUP BY q1.Num, q1.person_id, q1.person_name
HAVING SUM(q2.Weight) <= 1000
ORDER BY Num DESC
```

See it work here:

> https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=42efb4e2e71e95dcb54d59e780267857

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention the specific database but a generic version of the query can look like:

```
select person_name
from (
  select *, row_number() over(order by num desc) as rn
  from (
    select t.*, sum(weight) over(order by num) as aw from t
  ) x
  where aw <= 1000
) y
where rn = 1
```

Comment: Thank you! Actually your answer is more useful for reality, but no window function answer needed, I'm sure your answer will be voted, thank you again